# Отличие цвета текста в верстке от макета

Tags: html, wordpress, вёрстка, текст, дизайн

Верстаю страницу для Wordpress и столкнулся с проблемой. Текст на сайте имеет некую розовую обводку и визуально цвет кажется светлее, чем в оригинале. Можно ли это как-то исправить. Смотрел на других сайтах, где-то есть такая же обводка, где-то нет.

[image: розовый оттенок]

Comment: Кто-то открыл как работает ClearType. И нет, не надо это «чинить».

Comment: @AlexeyTen, окей, допустим я отключу это в винде, но почему я наблюдаю это не на всех сайтах? Или все зависит от цвета/шрифта?

Comment: @Malyuga так работает отрисовка шрифтов, но какое отношение всё это имеет к wordpress?

Comment: @Quazimorda, не знаю, я подумал, что это может быть причиной. Но теперь мне все понятно, спасибо